# Destroy modeless wxDialog on close

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to destroy a modeless wxDialog when the window is closed.
What I tried is:

```cpp
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

class MyDialog : public wxDialog {
public:
    MyDialog() : wxDialog(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Dialog", wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wxRESIZE_BORDER) {
        // Comment next 2 lines out for it to work as expected.
        auto* sizer = CreateButtonSizer(wxOK);
        this->SetSizerAndFit(sizer);
        Bind(wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, [this](wxCloseEvent &) { this->Destroy(); });
    }
};

class MyApp : public wxApp {
public:
    auto OnInit() -> bool override {
        if (!wxApp::OnInit()) {
            return false;
        }
        auto *dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog->Show(true);
        return true;
    }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

But for some reason the application does not exit.

Edit, from the comments thanks to @catalin:

- wxVersion: v3.1.5
- Deleting everything in the ctor except the `Bind` exits the app as expected.
- But just having something simple as a `new wxButton(this, wxID_OK, "OK")` in the ctor prevents the app from exiting.
- If the ctor is empty the app also doesn't exit when closing the dialog.

Edit2:

- Pressing the button or "ESC" does not exit the app. Pressing the "X" in top right (on Windows) closes it, but shouldn't the behaviour be the same according to the [documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_dialog.html):

> EVT_CLOSE(func): The dialog is being closed by the user or programmatically (see wxWindow::Close). The user may generate this event **clicking the close button** (typically the 'X' on the top-right of the title bar) if it's present (see the wxCLOSE_BOX style) or by **clicking a button with the wxID_CANCEL or wxID_OK ids**.

Last Edit (I hope):

- I somewhat solved it. Adding `Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, [this](wxCommandEvent &) {this->Destroy();});` closes the app on button click, the Bind for `wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW` closes it on "X" click. But still the `wxOK` Button should generate a `wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW` not a `wxEVT_BUTTON` event according to doc.

Comment: Which wxW version are you using? FWIW, if you use an empty `wxDialog` (no need for children, sizer etc.) with your code above (after you have made it compile...), the app will exit as expected when using latest wxW code (master, post-3.1.5).

Comment: I'm using v3.1.5. And I just confirmed deleting everything in the constructor except the `Bind` exits the app as expected.

Comment: @Teharez, did you look at the dialogs sample? Are you sure you want modelers dialog and not modal one?

Comment: Yes I looked at it, but couldn't find anything that helps. Maybe just bc. the sample is so big. And ideally I want a modeless dialog. Imagine sth like the windows explorer Properties window, without the ability to change values, just to display info, as use case.

Comment: @Teharez, when you look at the sample - check the functionality you are looking for. The sample might be big, but usually you just need a small portion of it to look at (`modeless dialog`  in your case) and see how to end the dialog. Just compile it, run it under the debugger and replicate the code in your project.

Comment: You're not showing the actual code you use because the above can't compile (`New` instead of `new`; missing `return true` at the end of `OnInit()`). Please show the actual code.

Comment: Ok updated the question. Sorry I tried to just copy&paste my code and removing the irrelevant parts without making a MVP. Also found out closing the window via "X" exits the application. See my Edit2.